# Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred

Tags: actionscript-3

I've read a lot of posts about this error. Yet it does not solve my problem. In my case, there are loop working through two funcions like this:

```
function getData() {
    //doing some stuff here
    call_socket("data", callback); //When response from socked server has been received, call callback function
}
function callback(data:Object) {
    if(!data) { getData(); } //if data is null, continue loop
    else { //stop the loop }
}
```

I got an error on both of these functions:

```
Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
```

I understand that this error tells me that I'm calling the functions repeatedly, but in my case, that is what I got to do there.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: The returned data for callback function is correct?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine. I've tested this code a lot of times. Only after an update it throwed me this error

Comment: show the `call_socket` method code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the logic of your code. Just think about situation when your call_socket does not return data for some time. This will result in numerous circles of callback and getData. Depending on your app you can achieve desired result in 2 ways:

1. You should use some Event to notify other parts of your app that the data has arrived (instead of callback)
2. You can poll the server at defined time spans. You may use Timer for this.

Comment: I think i didn't understand you. When socket has received the data from server and compiled all the chunks of the response, it will call that callback function. If it fails, it won't call it thus stopping the loop. There is no chance that getData() is called more that one time per socket call. But maybe you are right. Maybe using an event instead of callback function would work. I will test it

Comment: Your code shows that you will call getData method each time when callback method receives null as its data parameter. It does not matter if it happens just once per each socket call. The problem is that you will perform multiple socket calls whenever it returns null. And just think how many function call can be performed say in 1 seconds. This is why you are getting this stack overflow error. You said it worked previously. I guess you was just lucky because your socket call returned data very fast.